# Lookup string with substring key R

Tags: r, substring

I have a long list of strings, that share substrings. The list comes from event stream data, so there are tens of thousands of rows, but I'll simplify for this example; Pets:

```
+--------------------------------+
|              Pets              |
+--------------------------------+
| "one calico cat that's smart"  |
| "German Shepard dog"           |
| "A Chameleon that is a Lizard" |
| "a cute tabby cat"             |
| "the fish guppy"               |
| "Lizard Gecko"                 |
| "German Shepard dog"           |
| "Budgie Bird"                  |
| "Canary Bird in a coal mine"   |
| "a chihuahua dog"              |
+--------------------------------+
dput output: structure(list(Pets = structure(c(8L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 2L),.Label = c("A Chameleon that is a Lizard", "a chihuahua dog", "a cute tabby cat", "Budgie Bird", "Canary Bird in a coal mine", "German Shepard dog", "Lizard Gecko", "one calico cat that's smart", "the fish guppy"), class = "factor")), .Names = "Pets", row.names = c(NA,  -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to add information based on the *generic* type of pet (dog, cat, etc) and I have a key table that holds this information:

```
+----------+----------------+
|   key    | classification |
+----------+----------------+
| "dog"    | "canine"       |
| "cat"    | "feline"       |
| "lizard" | "reptile"      |
| "bird"   | "avian"        |
| "fish"   | "fish"         |
+----------+----------------+
dput output: structure(list(key = structure(c(3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("bird", "cat", "dog", "fish", "lizard"), class = "factor"), classification = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("avian", "canine", "feline", "fish", "reptile"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("key", "classification"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I use the "long string" from the `Pets` table to find relevant `classification` in the key table? The issue is, my lookup string contains the substring that is found in the key table.

I'm started by using grepl like this:

```
key[grepl(pets[1,1], key[ , 2]), ]
```

But this won't work because "calico cat" isn't in the key list, though "cat" is. The result I'm looking for would be "`feline`".

(Note: I can't simply switch things around because, in my own code, this sits within an apply function and loops through each row in the data. so, instead of `pets[1,1]` it's `pets[n,1]` In the end I intend to `cbind` the results onto the event stream data to do further analysis.)

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to do this. Any advice?

Comment: It appears that the key is always the second word of each "long string". Is this a reasonable assumption?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Strings have several to many different words. I just know that the `key` words are in there.

Comment: Then you should provide a sample with long strings that do not fit this assumption. Also, please provide your datasets by copy and pasting the output of `dput(my_data)` into your question, instead of how you currently formatted it

Comment: but it's ok to assume that two different `key`'s would _not_ appear in the same "long string"?

Comment: Yes, that is true, two substrings do not appear in the same long string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the package [fuzzyjoin](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin) to do these sorts of things very easily.

Here you can use [`regex_left_join`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin#example-of-regex_inner_join-classifying-text-based-on-regular-expressions), which works just like a normal left join (eg [`dplyr::left_join`](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html)), except that that the criteria for rwos being a match is determined by regular expression matching like [`stringr::str_detect`](http://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_detect.html)

```r
library(tibble)
library(fuzzyjoin)

pets <- tribble(
                            ~pets,
   "one calico cat that\'s smart",
             "German Shepard dog",
   "A Chameleon that is a Lizard",
               "a cute tabby cat",
                 "the fish guppy",
                   "Lizard Gecko",
             "German Shepard dog",
                    "Budgie Bird",
     "Canary Bird in a coal mine",
                "a chihuahua dog"
)

key <- tribble(
       ~key, ~classification,
      "dog",        "canine",
      "cat",        "feline",
   "lizard",       "reptile",
     "bird",         "avian",
     "fish",          "fish"
)

regex_left_join(pets, key, by = c("pets" = "key"), ignore_case = TRUE)

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>                            pets    key classification
#>                           <chr>  <chr>          <chr>
#>  1  one calico cat that's smart    cat         feline
#>  2           German Shepard dog    dog         canine
#>  3 A Chameleon that is a Lizard lizard        reptile
#>  4             a cute tabby cat    cat         feline
#>  5               the fish guppy   fish           fish
#>  6                 Lizard Gecko lizard        reptile
#>  7           German Shepard dog    dog         canine
#>  8                  Budgie Bird   bird          avian
#>  9   Canary Bird in a coal mine   bird          avian
#> 10              a chihuahua dog    dog         canine
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the list of keys for each Pet and then look them up in the table

```
Pattern = paste(KeyTable$key, collapse="|")
Pattern = paste0(".*(", Pattern, ").*")
Type = tolower(sub(Pattern, "\\1", ignore.case=TRUE, Pets))
KeyTable$classification[match(Type, KeyTable$key)]
 [1] "feline"  "canine"  "reptile" "feline"  "feline"  "canine"  "fish"   
 [8] "reptile" "canine"  "avian"   "avian"   "canine"
```

Data

```
KeyTable = read.table(text="key classification 
dog  canine
cat  feline   
lizard reptile
bird  avian    
fish  fish", 
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Pets  = c("calico cat",
"Shepard dog"  ,
"Chameleon Lizard", 
"calico cat",
"tabby cat",
"chihuahua dog",
"guppy fish",
"Gecko Lizard",
"Shepard dog",
"Budgie Bird",
"Canary Bird" ,
"chihuahua dog")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using `hashmap`:

```
library(hashmap)

hash_table = hashmap(Lookup$key, Lookup$classification)

Pets %>%
  separate_rows(Pets, sep = " ") %>%
  mutate(class = hash_table[[tolower(Pets)]]) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  select(Key = Pets, class) %>%
  bind_cols(Pets, .)
```

**Result:**

```
> hash_table
## (character) => (character)
##      [fish] => [fish]     
##      [bird] => [avian]    
##    [lizard] => [reptile]  
##       [cat] => [feline]   
##       [dog] => [canine] 

                           Pets    Key   class
1   one calico cat that's smart    cat  feline
2            German Shepard dog    dog  canine
3  A Chameleon that is a Lizard Lizard reptile
4              a cute tabby cat    cat  feline
5                the fish guppy   fish    fish
6                  Lizard Gecko Lizard reptile
7            German Shepard dog    dog  canine
8                   Budgie Bird   Bird   avian
9    Canary Bird in a coal mine   Bird   avian
10              a chihuahua dog    dog  canine
```

**Data:**

```
Pets = structure(list(Pets = c("one calico cat that's smart", "German Shepard dog", 
                               "A Chameleon that is a Lizard", "a cute tabby cat", "the fish guppy", 
                               "Lizard Gecko", "German Shepard dog", "Budgie Bird", "Canary Bird in a coal mine", 
                               "a chihuahua dog")), .Names = "Pets", row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


Lookup = structure(list(key = c("dog", "cat", "lizard", "bird", "fish"), 
                        classification = c("canine", "feline", "reptile", "avian", 
                      "fish")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("key", "classification"
                      ), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```